# Testing variable binding using Controller As syntax

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to test a simple form controller using the controller as syntax. What I want is to be able to pass in different field values to each unit test and see how the controller reacts. The code I'm using as an example:

Controller:

```
angular.module('auth').controller('LoginFormCtrl',['AuthService',function(AuthService) {
  var self = this;

  self.non_field_errors = {};

  self.login = function(){
    AuthService.login(self.login_details.username,self.login_details.password)
        .then(function(){
            //do routing stuff here
        },function(response){
            if('non_field_errors' in response){
                self.non_field_errors = response.non_field_errors;
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

Test:

```
describe('LoginFormCtrl', function() {

var scope; //scope to bind controller to
var ctrl; //Controller to be tested

beforeEach(module('auth'));

//Mock out AuthService
beforeEach(module(function($provide){

    authService = {
        login: function(username,password){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if(username == 'test1' && password == 'password1'){
                deferred.resolve();
            }else{
                deferred.reject({non_field_errors:['non_field_error_1']});
            }
            return deferred;
        }
    };
    $provide.value('AuthService',authService);

}));

//Set up scope
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
}));

//Set up spies
beforeEach(inject(function(AuthService){
    spyOn(AuthService,'login').andCallThrough();
}));

//Clean Up
afterEach(function(){
    ctrl = null;
});

it('should log the user in if they provide the correct details', inject(function($controller){

    ctrl = $controller('LoginFormCtrl',scope,{
        login_details:{
            username:'test1',
            password:'password1',
        }
    });

    ctrl.login();
    expect(AuthService.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test1','password1');
}));
```

});

I've tried a few different approaches such as creating a scope and directly manipulating the ctrl variable. What is the best way to do this kind of testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by instantiating the controller:

```
ctrl = $controller('LoginFormCtrl');
```

Angular will inject the AuthService. There is no other dependency to inject in the controller, so passing a scope or login_details won't work.

Then set its login_details:

```
ctrl.login_details = {
    username: 'test1',
    password: 'password1'
};
```

Then call the function to test:

```
ctrl.login();
```